# SAS unexpected truncation when recoding string

Tags: sas

When i try to recode a string into another string, I do not get the expected result:

Data:

```
data test1;
   input C_TNM_T $ ;
   datalines;
AZCD11  
AZCD10  
AZCD12
AZCD13
AZCD131
AZCD13A
AZCD13A1
AZCD13A2
AZCD13B
AZCD13B1
AZCD13B2
AZCD13C
AZCD14
;
```

I'm trying to recode AZCD12 to 'is':

```
data test2;
set test1;
 if C_TNM_T = 'AZCD11'   then _33_cT_temp   =  'a'   ;
 if C_TNM_T = 'AZCD10'   then _33_cT_temp   =  '0'   ;
 if C_TNM_T = 'AZCD12'   then _33_cT_temp   =  'is'  ;
run;
```

But 'AZCD12' is instead recoded to 'i' (as in the picture below). Why is this?

[image]

If I only recoded 'AZCD12' the result is what i expected:

```
data test2;
set test1;

 if C_TNM_T = 'AZCD12'   then _33_cT_temp   =  'is'  ;
run;
```

[image]

PS. Feel free to edit the title if you have a suggestion for at better description of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic conundrum that all SAS users will face at one point or another, and it can be a bit confusing due to how SAS works compared to other languages.  When you assign a value to the new variable `_33_cT_temp`, you are also initializing it at the same time. SAS will initialize the variable with the length of the first value it is assigned, and will determine whether it is a string or number based upon the value being assigned to it.

Consider three variables initialized in this program:

```
data test;
    NumVar = 50;
    CharVar1 = 'A';
    CharVar2 = 'AB';
run;
```

Running `PROC CONTENTS` on this dataset will show:

```
Variable    Type    Len
CharVar1    Char    1
CharVar2    Char    2
NumVar      Num     8
```

These are default assignments SAS will give on initialization. Notice that the numeric variable was automatically assigned a length of 8 bytes, while the character variables were different depending upon the length. Any subsequent assignments > 1 character (or byte) in `CharVar1` will result in truncating the value to 1 character.  This is why you are seeing the phenomenon in your data.

In your first `test2` dataset, `_33_cT_temp` is first being assigned a value of `a`. Like the above program, this initializes it to a length of 1, truncating the next value `is` to `i`. In your second `test2` dataset, `_33_cT_temp` is first being assigned a value of `is`, giving it a length of 2.

To get around this problem, you want to initialize the character variable first with the maximum length you think it will be. Space isn't nearly as much of a concern anymore, so you can be a lot more liberal with the assignment. Of course, you could scan the column to find the maximum possible length, but if you have a massive dataset and not a whole lot of computing resources, then it isn't worth it.

You can set the length with a `length` statement either at the very beginning of your program, or before you assign the first value of a variable:

```
data test2;
    set test1;
    length _33_cT_temp $2.;

    if(C_TNM_T = 'AZCD11') then _33_cT_temp = 'a';
    if(C_TNM_T = 'AZCD10') then _33_cT_temp = '0';
    if(C_TNM_T = 'AZCD12') then _33_cT_temp = 'is;
run;
```

You can also use the `length` statement as a way to set the column order of variables. Columns are set in the order that variables are initialized. If you changed the above program to:

```
data test2;
    length _33_cT_temp $2.;
    set test1;

    if(C_TNM_T = 'AZCD11') then _33_cT_temp = 'a';
    if(C_TNM_T = 'AZCD10') then _33_cT_temp = '0';
    if(C_TNM_T = 'AZCD12') then _33_cT_temp = 'is;
run;
```

You will find that `_33_cT_temp` is first. I use this trick a lot, particularly with large datasets containing lots of ID variables or dates. For example:

```
data a;
    length Date Hour Minute Second Cust_ID Trans_ID 8. 
           First_Name Last_Name $30.;
    set have;
    <code>
run;
```

Comment: Both answers given by stat and stu are excellent and answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

this isn't unexpected.
Since you don't specify a length for `_33_cT_temp` variable, lenght and type are automatically assigned to the first value the program encounters, in this case:

```
then _33_cT_temp   =  'a'   ;
```

So `_33_cT_temp` will be char ($) and with length 1 ('a' is only one char).
When you try to assign 'is' value, this will be truncated trying to fit into a variable of length 1.

The solution, and a good programming practice too, is to define length and type of new variable when the pdv is setup, after data and before set.

```
data new;
length _33_cT_temp $2;
set old;

[your statements]

run;
```

In the second case, you have the correct result (not truncated) because the first assigned value has length 2, hence the variable will be char with length 2.

Other cases of automatic length and type assignment could be:
if you don't specify length and type and you set a variable equal to another one (new=old), type and length of the new variable will be the same as the old one.
If you don't specify length and assign value with a CAT string function, default length will be 200. Uninitialized vars are missing numeric.
And so on...